# Having an issue with mantaflow fluid simulation with flow object inside of another object

Tags: fluid-simulation, collision, mantaflow

So I am working on a model currently of a banana being cut open that I am trying to make have blood come out when it's cut. I have animated the object being cut by swapping out the whole object for two split halves at a certain keyframe and I have the flow object inside a smaller duplicate of one of the halves that has its normals reversed so as to allow the flow object to recognize where to collide with the object. I've played around with resizing the objects and changing the flow resolution divisions to see if that was my issue and I was able to get fluid to come out of a separate banana half object that I set in the air but after resizing my original objects, no fluid comes out of my flow object. I have the outer banana parts not set as collision effectors for the fluid so I'm not sure what is stopping the fluid from flowing. I'm attaching a link to the project [here](https://gofile.io/d/2QgYYv). Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: please provide your blend file

Answer (score 1):

Your domain is too big with very low resolution (divisions) ... scale down Domain or increase Resolution.

---

Notes:

- your mesh has double vertices, Merge > by Distance <kbd>M</kbd>
- instead of creating inner effector object by dupli banana and scale down (that results in penetrated object from original banana at the end) ...

[image]

... use Solidify modifier (before Fluid modifier) on original banana and use this object as Effector directly, so you get perfectly fitted inner mesh and simpler scene to work with

- instead of Sphere for Inflow you can use Circle (or separated one banana loop), like that fluid comes from one direction (enable Flat) ... it depende how final result should looks like ...
- Instead of separate animation of Inflow object you can Parent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> Inflow object to animated Banana object to let move them together
- in this example I set start of fluid sim cache at frame 34

[image]

[image]

Comment: For where the camera is going to be, the effector intersecting with the banana is fine but does it have any effect on the physics of the fluid simulation? It shouldn’t if the outer banana isn’t a fluid simulation effector, correct?

Comment: Camera is now set from this side so I thought fluid will be visible ... ,but right it doesn't have an influence for sim :)

Comment: So changing the domain size and upping the resolution did work to make the fluid emit from my flow object but now the issue I’m getting is that at the frame that the knife chops the banana, the fluid exits the effector and gets on the chopping board and on top of the banana rather than staying contained. Is that an issue with effector solidity so as to contain the liquid or something else? I have the knife as an effector also so I don’t know if that’s having some effect.

Comment: Answer extended with sample file .. in hope it helps you solve the issue.

Comment: So I've varied my resolution divisions between 64 and 128 and changed the size of my domain but I'm back to the issue of no fluid coming out of my inflow object. [Link here](https://gofile.io/d/iHCwLv)

Comment: I should add, this is after following those steps you laid out, which made a lot of sense and cleaned the project up greatly.